# the onclick of a table row is also working on a textfield inside that row?

Tags: zen-cart

On the categories page Where all the products are listed in rows and each complete row is a link to that product details page.

In that row I have created a textfield and a submit button but the product details link is also working on the textfield which I does not want.

When I click in the textfield for writing something in it, it redirects me to the product details page and I am unable to write something in the textfield.

So How will I handle it so that I could write some value in textfield?

Answer (score 4):

This is just because of zen cart default code to redirecting user in case of clicking product row.

yo can change default behavior by two ways :

- Use JavaScript/JQuery

you can use below code to prevent default action while someone click on textbox

```
<script>
$(".sortTextBox").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
});
</script>
```

- Manually change code in PHP file

you need to change product listing code in `categories.php` file located in admin folder of zencart.

Answer (score 1):

Or, since you're changing the way the admin interface works, you could expand your changes to also remove the action that allows clicking on that table-row to be a quick access link to the details of that product (which is where editing of that product's information is normally handled).

For example, the onclick event in these code snippets would need to be removed:

```
        echo '              <tr class="dataTableRow" onmouseover="rowOverEffect(this)" onmouseout="rowOutEffect(this)" onclick="document.location.href=\''  . zen_href_link(FILENAME_CATEGORIES, zen_get_path($categories->fields['categories_id'])) . '\'">' . "\n";
```

and

```
        echo '              <tr class="dataTableRow" onmouseover="rowOverEffect(this)" onmouseout="rowOutEffect(this)" onclick="document.location.href=\'' . zen_href_link($type_handler , 'page=' . $_GET['page'] . '&product_type=' . $products->fields['products_type'] . '&cPath=' . $cPath . '&pID=' . $products->fields['products_id'] . '&action=new_product' . (isset($_GET['search']) ? '&search=' . $_GET['search'] : '')) . '\'">' . "\n";
```

And then you'd have to use the (e) edit button to gain access to the actual normal product edit screen, instead of the luxury of clicking anywhere on the row.